# PowerShell script to copy files, iterate duplicates with different time stamp, and ignore duplicates with same time me stamp

Tags: powershell, credentials

Let me start by saying, I really don't know powershell. I am an pharma process automation engineer so my experience is programming PLCs and HMI design. I have written all sorts of languages but I am by no means a programmer. But this is where we find ourselves, trying to write code for a solution that is needed and no one else knows how to do it.

I have two folders. One with unrestricted NTFS permissions, and one with read only permissions for everyone except local admins group. I need to copy files from the unrestricted folder to the one with read only permissions. I was going to use robocopy but I need to increment the file names if they exist in the destination with the same name but (different) time stamp and not copy it if the timestamp is the same. Robocopy can't do that.

I found a sample script that works for the incrementation, but does not consider the time stamp, the problem is that I am using task scheduler to trigger this script every time a PDF is printed. The script moves the printed PDF from one folder to the other, but the current script will keep making new copies with incremented numbering every time it is run. That won't work for what I need. I don't know powershell well enough to figure out how to have it consider the timestamp and increment files with different timestamps and ignore those with the same.

Here is the script I have so far:

```
function fcopy ($SourceDir,$DestinationDir)
{
    Get-ChildItem $SourceDir -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | ForEach-Object ($_) {
        $SourceFile = $_.FullName
        $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_
        if (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
            $i = 0
            while (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
                $i += 1
                $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_.basename + $i + $_.extension
            }
        } else {
            Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Verbose -Force
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Verbose -Force
    }
}
fcopy -SourceDir "C:\SoloVPE\UV1325A_Reports\" -DestinationDir "C:\UV1325A_Reports_Share\"
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].